# How do I display data from my express server in React frontend?

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to cobble together an Express backend that draws data from MySQL and a React frontend that lets me iterate through the data.

It seems that I am close (no errors, but nothing shows on React.)

What am I missing?

This is from qb.js on my server: (taken from https://dev.to/lisahjung/beginner-s-guide-to-using-mysql-database-in-a-node-js-app-49li)

```
const express = require("express");
const mysqlConnection = require("../utils/database");

const Router = express.Router();

Router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM quarterback_rankings",
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(results);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

Router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let qb = req.body;
  const sql =
    "SET @ID = ?;SET @Name = ?;SET @Position = ?;SET @Team = ?;SET @OpposingTeam = ?;SET @JodySmith = ?;SET @EricMoody = ?;SET @JohnFerguson = ?;SET @FantasyData = ?; CALL Add_or_Update_QB(@ID, @Name, @Position, @Team, @OpposingTeam, @JodySmith, @EricMoody, @JohnFerguson, @FantasyData);";
  mysqlConnection.query(
    sql,
    [
      qb.ID,
      qb.Name,
      qb.Position,
      qb.Team,
      qb.OpposingTeam,
      qb.JodySmith,
      qb.EricMoody,
      qb.JohnFerguson,
      qb.FantasyData,
    ],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        results.forEach((element) => {
          if (element.constructor == Array) res.send(element);
        });
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

Router.put("/", (req, res) => {
  let qb = req.body;
  const sql =
    "SET @ID = ?;SET @Name = ?;SET @Position = ?;SET @Team = ?;SET @OpposingTeam = ?;SET @JodySmith = ?;SET @EricMoody = ?;SET @JohnFerguson = ?;SET @FantasyData = ?; CALL Add_or_Update_QB(@ID, @Name, @Position, @Team, @OpposingTeam, @JodySmith, @EricMoody, @JohnFerguson, @FantasyData);";
  mysqlConnection.query(
    sql,
    [
      qb.ID,
      qb.Name,
      qb.Position,
      qb.Team,
      qb.OpposingTeam,
      qb.JodySmith,
      qb.EricMoody,
      qb.JohnFerguson,
      qb.FantasyData,
    ],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(
          "The data for the selected quarterback has been successfully updated."
        );
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

Router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "DELETE FROM quarterback_rankings WHERE ID= ? ",
    [req.params.id],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send("The selected quarterback has been successfully deleted.");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = Router;
```

I created a React app and set the proxy to match the express server.

Here is how I modified app.js (based on https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/calling-express-api-in-react-using-react-script-e19084a76a8a)

```
import React,  {Component} from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={qb: []};
}

  databaseList(){
    fetch("/")
    .then(res => {console.log(res);
      return res.json()})
    .then(qb => {
      console.log(qb);
      this.setState({qb})
    });
      
  }
  

render() {  
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        
        
          {this.state.qb.map(player =>
            <div key={player.ID}>Name: {player.Name} Position: {player.position}</div>)}
     
        </header>
     
    </div>
  );}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ Is the mySQL server running?

2/ What's the name of your database? "fantasy_football" ?

3/ Change the front part: Use a **functional component with hooks** (recent way to create react components).

4/ Install "axios" to fetch the data

```
npm i axios
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const [qb, setQb] = useState([]);

  // function to fetch the data from 'fantasy_football' database
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3005/fantasy_football');
      await setQb(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // React Hook that executes the fetch function on the first render 
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {qb.map((player) => (
        <div key={player.ID}>
          Name: {player.Name} Position: {player.Position}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you - I actually seemed to solve the issue by replacing ```"/"``` with ```"/qb"``` on both sides. What are the benefits of Axios?

Answer (score 0):

On a hunch, I changed `"/"` to `"/qb"` on the server and the fetch request.

Voila!

I wonder if `"/"` is too ambiguous...